# How to get always latest link to download tomcat server using shell

Tags: shell, tomcat

I have written a shell script to download and install the tomcat server **v (8.5.31)**. `wget http://www.us.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.31/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.31.tar.gz` It was working fine, but as soon the version got changed to `9.0.10`, it started giving error as **404 not found**.
So what should I do to get the latest version always.

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR

```
TOMCAT_VER=`curl --silent http://mirror.vorboss.net/apache/tomcat/tomcat-8/ | grep v8 | awk '{split($5,c,">v") ; split(c[2],d,"/") ; print d[1]}'`
wget -N http://mirror.vorboss.net/apache/tomcat/tomcat-8/v${TOMCAT_VER}/bin/apache-tomcat-${TOMCAT_VER}.tar.gz
```

I encountered the same challenge.
However for my solution I require the latest 8.5.x Tomcat version which keeps changing.

Since the URL to download Tomcat remains the same, with only the version changing, I found the following solution works for me:

```
TOMCAT_VER=`curl --silent http://mirror.vorboss.net/apache/tomcat/tomcat-8/ | grep v8 | awk '{split($5,c,">v") ; split(c[2],d,"/") ; print d[1]}'`
echo Tomcat version: $TOMCAT_VER
Tomcat version: 8.5.40
```

`grep v8` - returns the line with the desired version:

```
<img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"> <a href="v8.5.40/">v8.5.40/</a>                2019-04-12 13:16    -
```

`awk '{split($5,c,">v") ; split(c[2],d,"/") ; print d[1]}'` - Extracts the version we want:

```
8.5.40
```

I then proceed to download Tomcat using the extracted version:

```
wget -N http://mirror.vorboss.net/apache/tomcat/tomcat-8/v${TOMCAT_VER}/bin/apache-tomcat-${TOMCAT_VER}.tar.gz
```

This is the complete curl response from which the version is extracted using curl, grep and awk:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Index of /apache/tomcat/tomcat-8</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<h1>Index of /apache/tomcat/tomcat-8</h1>
<pre><img src="/icons/blank.gif" alt="Icon "> <a href="?C=N;O=D">Name</a>                    <a href="?C=M;O=A">Last modified</a>      <a href="?C=S;O=A">Size</a>  <a href="?C=D;O=A">Description</a><hr><img src="/icons/back.gif" alt="[PARENTDIR]"> <a href="/apache/tomcat/">Parent Directory</a>                             -   
<img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"> <a href="v8.5.40/">v8.5.40/</a>                2019-04-12 13:16    -   
<hr></pre>
<address>Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) Server at mirror.vorboss.net Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As I don't have enough reputation to answer to Jonathan or edit his post, here is my solution (tested with versions 8-10):

```
#!/bin/bash
wantedVer=9
TOMCAT_VER=`curl --silent http://mirror.vorboss.net/apache/tomcat/tomcat-${wantedVer}/|grep -oP "(?<=\"v)${wantedVer}(?:\.\d+){2}\b"|sort -V|tail -n 1`
wget -N https://mirror.vorboss.net/apache/tomcat/tomcat-${TOMCAT_VER%.*.*}/v${TOMCAT_VER}/bin/apache-tomcat-${TOMCAT_VER}.tar.gz
# Apache download link: wget -N https://dlcdn.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-${TOMCAT_VER%.*.*}/v${TOMCAT_VER}/bin/apache-tomcat-${TOMCAT_VER}.tar.gz
```

---

I had trouble with Jonathans code, because there were different versions downloadable at the same time which broke the composed download-link. In this solution, only the newest one is regarded. 
Altering the first line is enough to distinguish between different Main Versions.

Code Explained:

`curl` grabs an apache-directory-listing for the wanted tomcat-Version.

`Grep` then extracts all different Versions with a *positive lookbehind*, using the (-P) Perl regex pattern and keeping only the matching part (-o). 
Result: line(s) each containing one version Number in no particular order.

These lines get sorted by Version (`sort -V`) and only the last line (`tail -n 1`), in which is the greatest of all Versions is located, is assigned to the variable TOMCAT_VER.

At last, the download link is created with the gathered version information and downloaded via `wget` , but only if it is a newer version than present (-N).

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this code:

```
TOMCAT_URL=$(curl -sS https://tomcat.apache.org/download-90.cgi | grep \
 '>tar.gz</a>' | head -1 | grep -E -o 'https://[a-z0-9:./-]+.tar.gz')
TOMCAT_NAME=$(echo $TOMCAT_URL | grep -E -o 'apache-tomcat-[0-9.]+[0-9]')
```

It's not the most efficient way possible but it's very easy to understand how it works and it does work. Update the download-XX.cgi link to 10 if you want that version.

Then you can do:

```
curl -sS $TOMCAT_URL | tar xfz -
ln -s $TOMCAT_NAME apache-tomcat
```

and you will have the current version of Tomcat at apache-tomcat. When a new version comes out you can use this to do an easy update while keeping the old version there.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way using the official github mirror.
Basically, one has to query the github api for all available tags.
Afterwards, for each tag, the date has to be determined.
Finally, the tag with the latest date is the latest tag!

Try this script - let's call it `latest-tag`. It's dependent on [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). It takes a short while to execute, but should print the URL of the tarball of the lastest tag (currently: https://api.github.com/repos/apache/tomcat/tarball/TOMCAT_9_0_10)

```
#!/bin/bash
# Prints the url to the latest tag of given github repo
# $1: repo (e.g.: apache/tomcat )
# $2: optional github credentials. Credentials are needed if running into the api rate limit (e.g.: <user>|<user>:<authkey>)

repo=${1:?Missing parameter: repo (e.g.: apache/tomcat )}
[ -n "$2" ] && credentials="-u $2"
declare -a commits
declare -a tarball_urls
while IFS=, read commit_url tarball_url
do 
    date=$(curl $credentials --silent "$commit_url" | jq -r ".commit.author.date")
    if [[ "$date" > ${latest_date:- } ]]
    then
        latest_date=$date
        latest_tarball_url=$tarball_url
    fi
done < <( curl $credentials --silent "https://api.github.com/repos/$repo/tags" | jq -r ".[] | [.commit.url, .tarball_url] | @csv" | tr -d \")

echo $latest_tarball_url
```

Usage:

```
./latest-tag apache/tomcat
```

You might get hindered by the rate limit of the github api. 
Therefore, you might want to supply github credentials to the script:

```
./latest-tag apache/tomcat <username>
```

This will ask you for your github password. In order to run it interactively, you can supply the script with a personal [github api token](https://blog.github.com/2013-05-16-personal-api-tokens/):

```
./latest-tag apache/tomcat <username>:<api token>
```

Answer (score 0):

***Disclaimer - this solution uses screen scraping***

Find and download latest version of Apache Tomcat 9 for Linux or Windows-x64.
*Uses Python 3.7.3*

```
import os
import urllib.request

url_ends_with = ".tar.gz\""         # Use line for Non-Windows
url_ends_with = "windows-x64.zip\"" # Use line for Windows-x64

url_starts_with = "\"http"
dir_to_contain_download = "tmp/"
tomcat_apache_org_frontpage_html = "tomcat.apache.org.frontpage.html"
download_page = "https://tomcat.apache.org/download-90.cgi"

try:
    if not os.path.exists(dir_to_contain_download):
        os.makedirs(dir_to_contain_download, exist_ok=True)

    htmlfile = urllib.request.urlretrieve(download_page, dir_to_contain_download + tomcat_apache_org_frontpage_html)
    fp = open(dir_to_contain_download + tomcat_apache_org_frontpage_html)
    line = fp.readline()
    cnt = 1
    while line:
        line = fp.readline()
        cnt += 1
        if url_ends_with in line and url_starts_with in line:
            tomcat_url_index = line.find(url_ends_with)
            tomcat_url = line[line.find(url_starts_with) + 1 : tomcat_url_index + len(url_ends_with) - 1]
            print ("Downloading: " +  tomcat_url)
            print ("To file: " + dir_to_contain_download + tomcat_url[tomcat_url.rfind("/")+1:])
            zipfile = urllib.request.urlretrieve(tomcat_url, dir_to_contain_download + tomcat_url[tomcat_url.rfind("/")+1:])
            break
finally:
    fp.close()
    os.remove(dir_to_contain_download + "/" + tomcat_apache_org_frontpage_html)
```