# Strategy to keep Tomcat updated?

Tags: tomcat, redhat

I maintain a number of RedHat Enterprise Linux (both 7 and 8) servers (>100) with different applications. To keep my sanity, I'm of course using tools such as Ansible, and more to the point of this questions, locally mirrored copies of public RPM repositories (using Satellite Server for the purpose).

Updates are applied regularly from these repositories to keep the servers secure.

A few of these servers need Apache Tomcat installed. This is one of the few applications that is, to my knowledge, not available from any RPM-based repository; it must be installed manually from a tarball. Updates are also manual (aided by an Ansible role, but I still have to be aware of the new version and manually change it).

Are there any strategies to keep Tomcat up-to-date with little or no constant attention?

**Update:**

I found half of a solution to my problem. By default, Tomcat keeps the installation and the instance configuration mixed together in a single directory tree identified by CATALINA_HOME. That makes updating Tomcat without clobbering your configuration complicated.

To solve that, you can put the instance-specific files in a separate directory tree identified with the CATALINA_BASE variable. Upgrading Tomcat then becomes as easy as:

- Download the new tarball.
- Untar it to a new location
- Review the readme and changelog for any breaking changes.
- Update the CATALINA_HOME variable to point to the new location, while keeping the CATALINA_BASE variable unchanged.
- Restart Tomcat, using the scripts in the new CATALINA_HOME bin directory.

I am not providing code here because where and how you set CATALINA_HOME and CATALINA_BASE will vary. I set both variables in the service unit file that also starts Tomcat.

Still open: finding a way to automatically find out when a new release of Tomcat is published.

Comment: keep related  packages in some folder at ansible server. everytime for new update copy this folder to remote folder and run yum module to install those pkgs

Comment: @SAURABHPANDEY Thank you. I'm using a similar strategy, using Ansible to directly download Tomcat from an Apache mirror based on version number. But it doesn't solve the fundamental problem that I have to manually figure out when to update the version number, or with your approach, manually download the latest Tomcat tarball.

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of digging, I found the answers I needed. There are fundamentally two parts to my question:

- How to update Tomcat without breaking existing site configurations.
- How to find the current Tomcat version automatically.

## How to update Tomcat without breaking existing site configurations

The answer lies in using the CATALINA_HOME directory only for the actual Tomcat binary, and put the configuration into a separate directory specified with CATALINA_BASE.

The CATALINA_HOME directory should simply contain the content of the Tomcat tarball without modifications. You may delete certain files according to the Tomcat documentation, and you may want to add certain shared files, such as the tomcat-native libraries.

The CATALINA_BASE directory will contain the /conf, /webapp, /logs and a few other directories.

Before starting Tomcat, set and export both environment variables.

As an example, this is the systemd service unit template I use. I put it into /etc/system/systems/tomcat@.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache Tomcat Web Application Container for %I
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
Environment="CATALINA_HOME={{ usd_tomcat_catalina_home }}" "CATALINA_BASE={{ usd_tomcat_catalina_base }}/%i"
ExecStart=/bin/bash {{ usd_tomcat_catalina_home }}/bin/catalina.sh start
ExecStop=/bin/bash {{ usd_tomcat_catalina_home }}/bin/catalina.sh stop
SuccessExitStatus=126 143
User=tomcat
Group=tomcat

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The detailed instructions for using CATALINA_BASE are on the Tomcat documentation site.

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/introduction.html

## How to find the current Tomcat version automatically

The second problem is how to find the correct version of the Tomcat tarball to download. The Apache foundation will delete the tarball for one minor release when the next minor release is published.

Therefore, the following broke with a 404 error as soon as 9.0.45 was published.

```
wget https://mirrors.sonic.net/apache/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.44/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.44.tar.gz
```

This has been answered before on Stackoverflow here: [How to get always latest link to download tomcat server using shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51258801/how-to-get-always-latest-link-to-download-tomcat-server-using-shell)

```
TOMCAT_VER=`curl --silent http://mirror.sonic.net/apache/tomcat/tomcat-9/ | grep v9 | awk '{split($5,c,">v") ; split(c[2],d,"/") ; print d[1]}'`
wget https://mirrors.sonic.net/apache/tomcat/tomcat-9/v$TOMCAT_VER/bin/apache-tomcat-${TOMCAT_VER}.tar.gz
```

I found that the awk solution is somewhat brittle as the field numbers may move around. Doing the same thing with sed:

```
curl --silent http://mirror.sonic.net/apache/tomcat/tomcat-9/ | grep v9 | sed 's/.*v\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\).*/\1/'
```

The regular expression is looking for a sequence of v + digits + . + digits + . + digits. It then throws away everything except the digits and periods.

Answer (score 0):

```
[rohtash@172 blockinfile]$ cat cron.yml 
- hosts: remote1
  gather_facts: no 
  tasks:
  - name: create file in a min
    cron:
       name: "task"
       minute: "*/1"
       job: "/usr/bin/sh -c 'ansible-playbook update_pkgs.yml'"
```

on remote server you can check

```
[root@scp ~]# crontab -l
#Ansible: task
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/sh -c 'ansible-playbook update_pkgs.yml'
```

what cron module does, it will run this playbook every minute. Inside this playbook you can use when module like this

```
- include_tasks: yum_install.yml
  when: version != {{ what_you_earlier_saved }}
```

You can increase or decrease your cron job running timing minutes,day,hour,week whatever.

**what_you_earlier_saved** this variable you have to create and save in file like this

```
- shell: rpm -qa|grep python3-pip-wheel > lastversion
- shell: cat lastversion
  register: what_you_earlier_saved
```

after package updatation, everytime your ansible playbook will update this last version file.

Comment: Thank you! How would I know that a new version of Tomcat has been released? That is my main concern here. Also, I'm confused about your solution on another point. It looks like you would try to run an ansible playbook on the remote host instead of the controller. Why is that?

Comment: I didnt get your problem. You want to get updated online from internet or offline without internet. As if you are using internet you can just run yum module with state: latest. It will automatically update with latest version.

Comment: If you are going offline to install latest version, for that case u will have to go on internet and download latest package and update in that folder maually. Now this cron module will keep running this playbook and check your updates folder contains different package or same and accordingly will execute playbook.You can change hosts: parameter from remote to localhost if you want to run cron module on same server. Thats should not  be a issue

Comment: Is Tomcat available as an RPM from a yum repository? That would be the ideal solution, but I haven't found any repository that has it. Can you point me to which repo has it?

Comment: Prerequisites
I'm assuming a freshly installed RHEL 7 machine in this article, correctly subscribed, so we can install packages.

Installation
Installation is pretty straight forward, since the packages are available in the default channel (@rhel-7-server-rpms):

Raw
# yum install -y tomcat httpd
This will pull in all dependencies, esp. OpenJDK 1.8.

Comment: The tomcat version included in RHEL 7 is hopelessly outdated, and RHEL 8 does not include it at all. In any case, I found half a solution.

Answer (score 0):

For updates regarding new releases join the Tomcat mailing list tomcat-announce. 'The list is used to announce Tomcat releases, security vulnerabilities and other project announcements.'

https://tomcat.apache.org/lists.html#tomcat-announce

Comment: While that's generally a good idea, it misses the point of the question because it is not an automatic method.