# soap ws return error ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet

Tags: xml, web-services, tomcat, java-21

im in dire need of help. i planned on upgrading my soap webservice running on tomcat 8.5 with jdk 8 to the latest version. this might not be a useful information but previously i used netbeans 8.2. my current setup was netbeans ide 20, openjdk 21.0.1, tomcat 10.1.17. create new webservice using java with ant, and on libraries already present metro classes, jdk21, and i add library of jakarta ee 10 api library.

helloworld.java

```
package com.test.helloworld;

import jakarta.jws.WebService;
import jakarta.jws.WebMethod;
import jakarta.jws.WebParam;

/**
 *
 * @author NB042-19
 */
@WebService(serviceName = "testhelloworld")
public class testhelloworld{

    /**
     * This is a sample web service operation
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
    public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt) {
        return "Hello " + txt + " !";
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="6.0" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_6_0.xsd">
<!--    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>-->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>testhelloworld</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
        <!--<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>-->
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>testhelloworld</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

netbeans error log. i got this when try to go to webservice endpoint in the url (?wsdl)

```
11-Jan-2024 00:53:30.146 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-130] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Marking servlet [testhelloworld] as unavailable
11-Jan-2024 00:53:30.147 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-130] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Allocate exception for servlet [testhelloworld]
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1353)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1165)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1027)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2352)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:800)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1317)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1165)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:491)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:473)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:865)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:649)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:115)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:673)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Servlet 5.0 JAR throws compile error on javax.servlet.\* but Servlet 4.0 JAR does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64387472/servlet-5-0-jar-throws-compile-error-on-javax-servlet-but-servlet-4-0-jar-does) (e.g.: Use tomcat 9 or `jakarta.servlet`instead of `javax.servlet`)

Comment: Read following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66827542/strategy-to-keep-tomcat-updated

Comment: @OlafKock I've read this before, but i was adamantly proceed with Tomcat 10.1.17. But your comment makes me tried it. but hmm it kinda weird. on tomcat 9 it works perfect without the need to change to jakarta ee. but if i use jakarta ee 9, i got "404 Not Found: Invalid Request" after use the same setting. i thought of using jakarta ee since javax will going to deprecated soon